# Are deactivated plugins likely to slow down WordPress websites?

Tags: wordpress

Are deactivated plugins likely to slow down WordPress websites?

Website wordpress web-page speed is slow...

How I can improve wordpress web-page speed, do I need to update any new plugin or need to deactivate any plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Deactivated plugins consume almost no runtime resources. Not precisely zero runtime resources, but almost zero. Still, if you're in a production situation it's wise to delete them entirely.  Well-written plugins delete their data as part of the process of deleting themselves, and that can save table space and time. And, in this world full of cyber kiddies (wannabe cybercriminals) why leave an attack surface in place?

As for your site being slow: start by looking at Tools > Site Health. It may (or may not) identify some issues.

Try using [Lighthouse](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/#devtools) to identify whether your performance problems come from your server or from Javascript running in your users' browsers. Lighthouse will also identify oversized images and other slowdown causes.

There are tonnage of tutorials on the 'toobz about troubleshooting slow WordPress sites. Try doing some of those things, and ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

A WordPress site can be a personal blog with ten posts, a store with a million products for a sale, or anything in between. It's not possible to offer specific advice without knowing a lot more about your exact situation.